# Pagination for custom post type on page template

Tags: wordpress, navigation, pagination, custom-post-type

Hello I am trying to add pagination to a page template which I am using to display a custom post type. I have looked around for a few hours but I haven't come across clear set of instructions to follow.

Below is all the code from my page template php file. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

I would appreciate any help on how to add the code for

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Testimonials
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="container_12">          

            <div id="content" class="grid_8">           
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <div id="testimonials">                 
                    <?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; $testimonials = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'testimonial', 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => '2', 'paged' => $paged) ); ?>
                        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                        <ul>
                            <?php while ($testimonials->have_posts()) : $testimonials->the_post(); ?>
                                <li> 
                                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                                    <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>                              
                                </li>       
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </ul>
                        <?php else : ?>  
                        <p><?php _e('No entry found.'); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>     
                    <div class="navigation">
                   <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('« Older Entries') ?></div>
                   <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries »') ?></div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- #testimonials -->                

            </div><!-- #content --> 

                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>                     

        </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I'm able to access the page 2 with direct link testimonials/page/2/. But on page 1, the navigation does not appear.

**Page 1:**

[image]

**Page 2:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should reset your post data after WP query, as I think.

Check StackExchange people answers to this
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89191/using-query-posts-inside-single-php-loop

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try using `query_posts()` instead and see if this solves the problem.